# django website is giving 404 error for static files

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

Having problem with staticfiles in Django 2.

```
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
        STATIC_URL = '/static/'
        STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
        STATICFILES_DIR = [
              (BASE_DIR + "static/"),
        ]


        STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
              'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
             'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        ]
```

And my static structure is like below

[image]

I am getting 404 for statics. Tried different things but no success. btw collectstatic has been already performed. Another thing is when i make changes in the static folder, collectstatic is not collecting anything. it says "unmodified".

i am newbie in Django. appreciate for your help.

---

UPDATE 2:

New structure is below
[image]

and the settings is like

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static' )
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

When i try to collectstatic, there is no change. seems it is not collecting. and 404 returns for statics naturally since it is not collecting.

Comment: have you set django.core.context_processors.static in your context-processor list in settings.py?

Comment: nop. there is no TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in default one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

**1.** is the syntax error that Digitiain pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48251976/1622937):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

**2.** You cannot add the path in `STATIC_ROOT` to your `STTATICFILES_DIRS`. So if your `STTATICFILES_DIRS` looks like above, `STATIC_ROOT` cannot be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`.

---

The first point should be fairly clear. The second also confused me in the beginning. But it makes a lot of sense actually:

In `STATICFILES_DIRS` you tell django where to go and look for static files. This not primarily to serve them, but to collect them! The point is that on a productive server, django is not supposed to serve static files; this task should be handled by the web server. [Check the docs for details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) The idea is that you run the command [`python manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#deployment) and django will go through all the paths in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, collect the static files and put them... - exactly! - in the `STATIC_ROOT` folder. Now it becomes clear why the `STATIC_ROOT` folder cannot really be part of `STATICFILES_DIRS` as this would mean django would need to put the folder into itself. Again, this is in the case of a productive server. During development django can handle static files without help of a web server, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) is more from the docs on that.

I hope that helps to clarify the relation between `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`. Bottom-line: Choose a different path for `STATIC_ROOT` and you should be good to go!

---

As **an example**, you could have a project structure like this:

```
base_dir/
  - static/
      - css/
      - js/
      - ...
  - static_collected/
  - ...
```

Then it would be valid to define:

```
# settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_collected")
```

Comment: yea really confusing at first. now my config is STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static" )
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static") and collectstatic is working. but i guess having problem with path since it is creating new static folder out of project folder if it is not normal behavior for django

Comment: @CorpusCallosum please note that if `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static" )` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static")` then **STATIC_ROOT is inside STATICFILES_DIRS**! If `BASE_DIR` is in `STATICFILES_DIRS` then any dir withing `BASE_DIR` cannot become the `STATIC_ROOT`. Please just choose some random folder **outside** `BASE_DIR` for your `STATIC_ROOT` and try if things work better.

Comment: @CorpusCallosum added an example. I hope this helps to get your setup running. Let me know if it should still not work.

Comment: really appreciate your effort. i added an update to the original question.

Comment: @CorpusCallosum sorry to hear that it still does not work. do you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` under INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yep thats the first thing i have controlled. This becomes really pain in the ass. Really weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163158/discussion-between-jojo-and-corpuscallosum).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a red herring, but in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) the syntax for setting a path relative to your BASE_DIR includes `os.path.join`, so yours would look like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

EDIT: I also just noticed that you referenced `DIR` rather than `DIRS`, which could be causing grief. Ditto with [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES).

Comment: when i use join, it says ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting. thats why changed to string conct.